# I can't change php settings in plesk

Tags: php, plesk, plesk-onyx

As shown below, I can't change any of these PHP settings in plex onyx.

[image]

Is there any other way to change these settings, or some workaround?

Comment: Bro - you didn't even say what you've already tried. Please say what you've tried, and what you think the issue might be so we can help you more quickly.

Comment: I found this  from plex support website: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213936565-How-to-find-and-edit-PHP-configuration-files-in-Plesk-for-a-domain-or-for-global-PHP-handler

Comment: and this: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001152233-How-to-customize-PHP-settings-in-Plesk

Comment: sorry, I guess I wasn't clear enough - The screenshot is of the PHP settings page, and the settings which should be there are just plaintext with no way to interact with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can change these settings using `ini_set` function for specific file or for complete project by including this change in all files. You can write code as below:

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", 120);
```

Also, you can make change using .htaccess file as well

```
php_value max_execution_time 120
```

Hope it helps you.